# Globally changing format of negative currency numbers in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

We have a large ASP.NET MVC project where all numbers output to the screen are formatted as currency (i.e. ToString("c").  However, negative numbers are showing up with ()'s.  For example:

```
decimal d = -8.88m;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("c"));
//outputs $(8.88)
```

This is a bit annoying to our users, particularly since there are in textboxes.  We have a few thousand places where we send currency fields to the screen like this, so we'd love a way to change the formatting globally.  Is there one?  All the methods I've seen indicate that you have to create a new formatter, similar to this:

```
 string curCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
 System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo currencyFormat =
     new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(curCulture).NumberFormat;
 currencyFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
```

We'd prefer not to change all of our ToString("c") methods ... is there a better way?  My first thought was to just change our locale to Australia, but realized the date formatting would be screwed up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aliostad was close... Try this in your base controller:

```cs
System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
modCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = modCulture;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are in the right track. But instead of creating a new formatter, change current thread's negative format:

```
// update: dont use this!
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
```

You can put this when the request is initiated and in ASP.NET one and only one thread is responsible for handling a request so this will affect all your currency formattings (unless you yourself create a new thread in which case you have the option to change it).

**Update**

Yes above does not work because it is read-only! try this:

```
Console.WriteLine((-111.98).ToString("c"));
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Console.WriteLine((-111.98).ToString("c"));
```

Comment: I was excited, but this didn't work - I received an InvalidOperationException ... "Instance is readonly"

Comment: HI Jess, I actuallty did not try it and I had a suspicion something in the line will be read only. see my update.

Comment: Yep, that works.  I marked the other person's answer as correct since he was first though.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the advantage over the other answers that it clones the system's other existing `CurrentCulture` settings and sub-settings instead of resetting them to the named culture's defaults:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

### Alternate solution

Has an additional advantage that it only overrides `CurrencyNegativePattern` if the system is set to `en-US` and the system does not have an existing custom `CurrencyNegativePattern` setting (on top of the advantage of solution I included above):

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en-US", StringComparison.Ordinal)
    && Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern == 0)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
}
```