# Asp.Net Base Controller (non MVC)

Tags: .net, controller, radix

I'm trying to implement the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994601/globally-changing-format-of-negative-currency-numbers-in-c-sharp/9087065)

My project is just an asp.net web application (not MVC)

Can this be done and how do i go about to modifying the base controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class YourPage : BasePage {


}

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
         // ... localization/globalization code here ...
         base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx. so for teh basePage: System.Web.... i can make a separate class for it? and it'll apply to all pages?  or do i have to include that in every page i want the globalization code to aply?

Comment: @robert Yes, make sure your pages inherit from your `sub-class`ed `BasePage`